# After filtering value than enable sorting link on relational field in Grid View Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, filtering, yii2

When I first time filter or sort the field of gridview ,after that enable the relational data field sorting link,
so, how can i solve this issue.

Here i attached two image that describe the before filtering or sorting and after that.

Link Url :

before filter:    https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDJoG.png
after filter:     https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXnfY.png

**Updated:**

I have a two table one of is `student_info` and second one is `student_trans`. and i create relation `student_info_id (primary key)` with  `student_trans_info_id` like `(student_info_id = student_trans_info_id)`,

Now in `student_trans` grid view i used the student_info's `first_name` and `last_name` field with sorting and filtering, but these relational field's sorting link enable after filter or sort the any filed of `student_trans` grid view field.

Comment: I'm not seeing the images. Link directly? The rest of your post is also confusing.

Comment: i added updated image URL for after filtered image : [link] http://smartmusicstore.esy.es/images/after_filter.png  and secong before filtered image : [link] http://smartmusicstore.esy.es/images/before_filter.png

Comment: Im sorry, i still cant understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After do googling i found my mistake.

My mistake was that i added `$dataProvider->sort->attributes[]` code after `$this->load();` function; so it mean after loading the filtered data than enable sorting link.

Now, i resolved my mistake with put the  `$dataProvider->sort->attributes[]` before `$this->load();` function.

Thanks to `**@Paul van Schayck**` post....